# Oracle schema optimization for 1 : 0..1 relationship

Tags: performance, oracle, query-optimization

I have two tables that look like this:

```
table A: FieldID NUMBER (PK), other non-relevant fields
table B: FieldID NUMBER (PK/FK), other non-relevant fields
```

The tables map a 1 : 0..1 relationship. Specifically, after a new row is inserted in table A, at some point in the future table B will be populated with additional data.

This design was originally preferred to a unique extended table so to have non-nullable fields everywhere (as there is no possibility to predict when the "B" portion of data will be populated).

Now... The performance of a join select from A and B is surprisingly awful. We are talking about a few 100k rows in both tables, and yet a simpe inner join takes a huge amount of time to complete.

Aside from moving the fields from B in A (a thing I'd rather not do to avoid the extra "null" checks), how may I improve my performances?

Comment: Define "awful", in particular is it for single PK queries or FULL TABLE SCAN?

Comment: Hi, it is for a PK search. If I make (for instance) select * from A, B where A.FieldID = B.FieldID and rownum <= 10, it takes ~ 20 seconds to complete.

Comment: Please post the explain plan. [Tracing the query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/sqltrace.htm#PFGRF01020) may also help understand why it takes so much time.

Answer (score 1):

Do your join like this: `SELECT /*+GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/ ... FROM .. WHERE ...;` And then, show us the output of: `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));`

This will show the execution plan with associated statistics, as estimated and actually found when executing the query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your consideration. I have no access to this functionality, but I will ask my dba to provide it to me.

Comment: Let's hope you get it. Access to execution plans and this sort of cardinality feedback information is essential for performance analysis of queries.

Comment: @Andrea Tell him some random guy from the internet asked you. ;) More seriously, as @DavidAlridge said, this is essential if you want to pin point the real problem. Or you can use `set autotrace` in sql*plus, it's better than nothing but you don't get the difference between expected and actual rows.

Comment: @Andrea - Alternatively if your DBA won't grant you the access tell them "that's okay,  you tune the query.  after all, it is your job".

Answer (score 1):

If you are equi-joining the two tables for all rows then you should get the best performance from a hash join. If the smaller set of joined data can be cached then the cost is only slightly more than a full scan of both tables, which is about as efficient as you can get.

If you are joining only small numbers of rows than a hash cluster may be helpful, as it physically co-locates the rows of the two tables and makes a join very efficient for small numbers of rows. The downside is that a full scan of either, particularly the smaller table, will be more expensive and so will inserts.